# How to use git flow in GitLab

Tags: gitlab, git-flow

We're using GitLab for our project and we think it's great.
We're also using git flow to manage the changes in feature, develop, master branches.

Can you use the Merge Request build in GitLab to manage the branches in git flow style?

Meaning when accepting a Merge Request for a release branch, it will merge the release branch into master AND into develop.. 
Or should we always use git flow on our local machines to accept the Merge Requests.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this [issue 1628](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/1628) illustrates, it is best to use GitLab to publish (push) branches, then to rely on a specific GitLab feature related to a [particular workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18188492/6309) like git-flow.

So the natural approach is to limit those git-flow features to the local clones, and push to GitLab any branch you want, once the merge request is resolved.

Comment: Thanks. Git-flow indeed seems to be a little bit over the top since we're also deploying constantly.

Answer (score 1):

By now, there is something called [GitLab Flow](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/gitlab_flow.html), "a clearly defined set of best practices".

Cited from the linked source:

> It combines feature-driven development and feature branches with issue
>   tracking.